# redux-router different transition for different pages and back button

Tags: css-transitions, react-router, react-router-redux

I am writing an application with `redux-router` and I am using a `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` to animate between pages like so:

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
          component="div"
          transitionName="moveLeft"
          transitionEnterTimeout={700}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={700}
        >
          {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
            key: this.props.location.pathname
          })}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    );
  }
}
```

The project I am working on has an `index` page and `articles`. How would I show different transitions depending on whether the user moves from the `index` to an `article` and vice versa? And will this also cover the back button automatically?